# Stack examining with GDB. What is x/[n][x] $[reg]?

Tags: c, gdb

I am new to GDB and how software works on a low level. 
Currently I am reading book «HACKING the art of expoitation» by Jon Erickson.
I know what is stack, what is stack pointer, base pointer and etc. I can easily understarnd `info stack` command, but what is `x/[n][x] $[reg]`?
Example from book:

```
0x08048344 <test_function+0>: push ebp  
0x08048345 <test_function+1>: mov ebp,esp  
0x08048347 <test_function+3>: sub esp,0x28  
0x0804834a <test_function+6>: mov DWORD PTR [ebp-12],0x7a69  
0x08048351 <test_function+13>: mov BYTE PTR [ebp-40],0x41  
0x08048355 <test_function+17>: leave  
0x08048356 <test_function+18>: ret  
...  
(gdb) x/16xw $esp  
0xbffff7c0: 0x00000000 0x08049548 0xbffff7d8 0x08048249
0xbffff7d0: 0xb7f9f729 0xb7fd6ff4 0xbffff808 0x080483b9
0xbffff7e0: 0xb7fd6ff4 0xbffff89c 0xbffff808 0x0804838b
0xbffff7f0: 0x00000001 0x00000002 0x00000003 0x00000004
```

What is that? As I know this command shows 16 last var's addresses stored in stack.
But what is `0xbffff7c0 0xbffff7d0 0xbffff7ce`? How to read it? and why there is a 10 byte shift always?

Explain please.

Comment: The part at the left is memory addresses. Each line is 16 bytes, so the numbers go up by 16, which is 10 in hex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 0xbffff7c0 is memory address
 0x00000000 0x08049548 0xbffff7d8 0x08048249 is the content of the 0xbffff7c0 in hexa format
```

in general :

```
 x/nfu addr
```

> **n**, **f**, and **u** are all optional parameters that specify how much memory to display and how to format it; **addr** is an expression
>   giving the address where you want to start displaying memory. If you
>   use defaults for nfu, you need not type the slash `/'. Several
>   commands set convenient defaults for addr.

Read moore [here](http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/gdb/gdb_56.html)